# why use $A = \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i ,E_{i+1} \subset E_{i}$ ,instead of $A=\lim_{i\to\infty}E_i$.

Tags: real-analysis

In real analysis, why use $A = \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i ,E_{i+1} \subset E_{i}$ ,instead of $A=\lim_{i\to\infty}E_i$.Are they the same things?

Is it because we prefer to use limits on real Numbers rather than on sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that to define a limit, you need a topology. What topology would you use to define $A=\lim_{i\to\infty}E_i$? Or more generally, how would you define this limit?

At the end, a definition of the limit in this case is... $ \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$.

Comment: My bad, it is a typo, where the set $E_i$ should be decreasing.

Comment: So, it comes first the $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$, then we have a definition of the set limit.

Answer (score 1):

If $(E_i)$ is an increasing sequence, then $\lim_{i\to\infty}E_i= \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. The condition you write implies the existence of the limit. But the converse does not hold. The limit can exists, e.g., also if you have an incresing sequence of sets.